# generic breadcrumb in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Please help me as i m totally new to asp.net mvc.I want to implement generic breadcrumb in asp.net mvc. So i created a partial view(cshtml) and all it in all pages and in the Partial View,i embed the logic to show BreadCrumbs and its working fine.But problem is that, a page can be open in two ways

1. through dashboard
2. through Menu

My Coding handles only one scenario(either dashboard or menu), Can anyone please simplify this scenario or guide me to apply breadcrumb in all the pages.

So i want this

1. if a user enters Customer's page , from the menu then the breadcrumb should show the hierarchy from the menu like Admin > Customer
2. and if a user enters customer's page from the dashboard then the breadcrumb should show the hierarchy from the dashboard like Dashboard > Customer

Thanks in Advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at

> MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5

I have used it in the past for the same kind of thing. Wrapping bootstrap around it to give some better styling